# How to get request token and secret in OAuth 1.0a

Tags: java, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to get oAuth working for accessing QuickBooks Online. I have a QuickBooks login/connect button embedded on a page that triggers the whole oAuth process. When it's clicked, a window pops up that is directed towards my apps getRequestToken endpoint. The handler (servlet) issues a request to the QuickBooks oAuth request token API, and it gets back:

- Request Token
- Request Token Secret
- Authorization URL

So I have the response send a redirect to the Authorization URL. The pop up window now displays a QuickBooks login, after which there is a request to authorize my app with the users account. Once that's done, the pop up window is redirected to my apps getAccessToken endpoint (the callback URL that I included when calling the request token API).

From there, I obviously have to send a request to the QuickBooks oAuth access token API to get an access token and access secret, but apparently I need to supply:

- Request Token
- Request Token Secret
- oauth_verifier

The oauth_verifier is provided as a parameter in the callback to my getAccessToken endpoint, as well as an oauth_token, but I don't understand how to get hold of the request token and request token secret from here. Am I supposed to have my getRequestToken endpoint store them somewhere once they're retrieved.

I'd prefer not to, but is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I supposed to have my getRequestToken endpoint store them somewhere once they're retrieved?

Yes. :-)

Does that answer the question? Yes, you need to temporarily store the request token somewhere while you wait for the user to arrive back on your site.

Comment: since the OAuth "dance" is browser-based I've found that setting a server cookie is the easiest way to persist the token; given the signature required there's minimal security risk (the cookie is deleted as soon as the accessToken is granted).